# how to get a web page component loading speed report from a non-technical user

Tags: web-server, performance, performance-monitoring, network-speed

We have a portal app which pulls in components from a number of different web servers. Some of our US users are reporting very slow page loading times.

I would usually use the firefox/firebug and the net panel to review which components and servers are slow, however I cannot replicate the problem.

It seems impossible to export the firebug report to a text file or similar to send to a technician, so is there a similar alternative plugin for either firefox or internet explorer that a non-technical user can install which would send component loading time reports back to base?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Pingdom Full Page Test](http://tools.pingdom.com/) and see if it will duplicate the issue.  I am not sure where their server is, but the testing is done server side (as verified by Fiddler) and you get a cool graph:

[image: page load test graph for MrMediaTraining.com]

and a permalink to the [test results](http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/?url=http://mrmediatraining.com/&id=2796341).  From their text:

> The Full Page Test loads a complete
>   HTML page including all objects
>   (images, CSS, JavaScripts, RSS, Flash
>   and frames/iframes). It mimics the way
>   a page is loaded in a web browser.

Comment: this looks pretty good as well. its slightly limited compared to yslow as I can't get a report of various interactions only the assets referenced from the URLS. but its good

Comment: yes, a remote version of YSlow or a way to auto publish the YSlow results would be helpful in situations where you are using a content delivery system.

Answer (score 1):

YSlow gives you some nice report & overall rating for different performance points.  You tried that?

Comment: Yeah, that looks good. I guess it would be cool if yslow had an email this report option, but that is probably asking too much.

Answer (score 0):

Yes [Tamper Data](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/966/) for Firefox can do it. See https://addons.mozilla.org/img/uploads/previews/full/2/2680.png?modified=0 .

Although if sending back a report is necessary, this is not possible.

Comment: I need the report